# No such file of directory Windows 10 PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

Till now the command i use to convert HDR videos to SDR worked just fine till now. I am gettong always the error message "`F:\_4k_Movies_\Dolittle: no such file or directory`" any idea what's whong?

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i F:\_4k_Movies_\Dolittle 4K.mkv -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,
zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,
format=yuv420p -c:v libx265 -crf 10 -preset fast F:\_4k_Movies_\Dolittle.SDR.mkv
```

Comment: Put quotes around the path because it contains a space character: `"F:\_4k_Movies_\Dolittle 4K.mkv"`

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error. I cannot understund why doesn't recognize the file path.

Comment: Then it looks like you quoted wrong. The error shows the path is cut off at the space character. Show us exactly what you did.

Comment: The first thing i always do is to open the C:\Users\Costadinos Chatzis\Desktop\FFmpeg x64\bin where ffmpeg.exe is, shift+right-click and in the menu appears i choose Open PowerShell window here. The PowerShell enviroment apears and ready to run ffmpeg.exe. Then i type the following command using the quotes correctly. I am sure for this. No space character. And it tells me "F:\_4k_Movies_\Dolittle: no such file or directory" I don;t know why when copy paste here the command the quote replaced with space character!

Comment: Problem solved. The problem wasn't to read the file. It was the output file. I re-write (not copy-paste) the output path and it worked!